# Audio volume jumps to ~98% with Bluetooth headphones connected

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth

This has been happening for about a month.

I’ve been trying to figure out the cause, but can’t figure out steps to make it happen.

This is on an iPhone 11 Pro Max 13.3.1 (not sure if it started on that update or not). My headphones are Sony WH-1000MX3. (I also have AirPods and haven’t noticed it happening with them. But I almost always have the AirPods turned up all the way so that might be why)

Two times I’ve noticed it happens more often is when I open a new tab in safari or when I swipe to the app switcher. (But neither does it every time and I’ve seen it happen other times)

Thankfully it rarely happens when audio is playing. Maybe never. I almost always notice the new volume level ui and turn it down.

Comment: The _volume_ of the audio jumps?

Comment: Yes. It jumps to not quite full volume. 98% is just a guess

Comment: This is still going on, although for about a day a while back it was setting itself to ~50% instead of ~98%, but now it is back to ~98%.

Comment: Have you tried setting the volume to 0 before powering the AirPods down?

Comment: 98% is quite precise. How did you come up with that number?